# git and Umlauts

Tags: ios, macos, git

I had a folder named "TransportAufträge" on MAC OSX which was versioned by git.
I then changed the name (before committing) to "TransportAuftraege".

Now when trying to commit, I get the following error message:

> error: pathspec '"App/ViewControllers/TransportAuftra\314\210ge/TransportAuftraege.h"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>   error: pathspec '"App/ViewControllers/TransportAuftra\314\210ge/TransportAuftraege.m"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>   error: pathspec '"App/ViewControllers/TransportAuftra\314\210ge/TransportAuftraege.xib"' did not match any file(s) known to git.

It seems like git did not notice that I renamed the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When renaming a file under source control, you should use Git to do the rename, e.g.

```
git mv TransportAufträge.h TransportAuftraege.h
git mv TransportAufträge.m TransportAuftraege.m
git mv TransportAufträge.xib TransportAuftraege.xib
```

Fortunately, you should be able just to rename the files back to the original names (using Finder or the normal `mv` command) and then run these `git mv` commands.

Comment: It is the folder I have renamed, not the files. Would it be: git mv TransportAufträge/ TransportAuftrarge ?